# AWS DocumentDB Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, aws-documentdb

My AWS DocumentDB was working alright, but suddenly it started throwing the below error.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at Timeout._onTimeout (app-path\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'ServerEndpoint' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

I haven't made any changes in the environment both at the client or at the AWS Console end. I am not able to make head or tail of this.

Can someone suggest.

Comment: Is every connection failing with the application suddenly? Can you manually test a TLS connection from mongoshell from the same application server? It will help rule out if there is an application connection issue, or connection issue to server.